# Netbeans Java Module Interaction

Tags: java, netbeans, module

What is the methodology to handle this in `Netbeans`?

Module **A** and **B** are top components

1. A implements and interface that B uses to interact with A.
2. B uses Lookup API to find A but gets a new instance of A, which being a new instance doesn't update the gui of original A thats displayed.
3. Basically B needs to talk to the original instance of A.
4. Being loosely coupled the parent of A and B shouldn't be sending the instance of one to the other.

With `Netbeans` the parent is the Windows application which doesn't seem to even have a editable coding area to send the instance around.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to split to ATopComponent and some AStorage (for example). ATopComponent should implement LookupListner on AStorage.

For searching ATopComponent you should you WindowManager.getDefault().find(id of ATopComponent)